# Show the following is logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Show that

$$p \leftrightarrow (q \land r) \equiv (\lnot q \lor \lnot r) \leftrightarrow \lnot p $$

I can't use a truth table.

I'm really confused. So if you could explain using the law.

This is what I got

LHS:

= $\lnot p \leftrightarrow \lnot(q  \land r)$

= $\lnot p \leftrightarrow (\lnot q  \lor \lnot r)$

Comment: Have you already proved that $p\leftrightarrow q\equiv\neg p\leftrightarrow\neg q$?

Comment: Is that one of the laws? I have a table here and I didn't see that but that seems to be equivalent

Comment: It isn’t one of the equivalences that are usually considered basic laws, but it’s not too hard to prove using the fact that $p\leftrightarrow q$ is equivalent to $(p\to q)\land(q\to p)$.

Comment: So like in this case, which side would be better to start with? Because I could easily change the left side $(q \land r)$ into the $(\lnot q \land \lnot r)$ but then after it gets confusing. Also how would I change the arrow to the or symbol.

Comment: My inclination would be first to prove that $(s\leftrightarrow t)\equiv(\neg s\leftrightarrow\neg t)$ as a general rule and then to let $s=p$ and $t=q\land r$; after that all you need is one application of De Morgan’s law.

Comment: I edited the question to what I got so far, but after that I'm confused, I could be totally wrong too.

Comment: You have an extra negation: if you’re going to use the equivalence that I suggested (which will still need to be proved), the lefthand side is equivalent to $\neg p\leftrightarrow\neg(q\land r)$, which is equivalent to $\neg p\leftrightarrow(\neg q\lor\neg r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT for the revised question: Complete the calculation so that you end up with $(\neg q\lor\neg r)\to\neg p$:

$$\begin{align*}
p\to(q\land r)&\equiv\neg p\lor(q\land r)\\
&\equiv\neg p\lor\neg\big(\neg(q\land r)\big)\\
&\equiv\neg p\lor\neg(\neg q\lor\neg r)\\
&\equiv\ldots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I think I made a error in my question, I meant to say $\to$ not $\leftrightarrow$

Comment: would that change the change the answer?

Comment: @Shawn: It makes it *much* easier. I’ve revised my answer to match; you should do the same to the question itself.

Comment: I dont get why you changed the $\to$ to $\or$, but the last calculation you did, all I have to do is the de Morgans law correct?

Comment: @Shawn: I assumed that you knew that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$; you really do need that equivalence, so far as I can see. I’ve already made the one application of De Morgan’s law that’s needed; the last step (or two, depending on how fussy you’re required to be) requires something else.